# SkinID on usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, themes, skin

I have created a usercontrol (a custom button control), how to apply skin on that control.
What to write in the skin file for eg for a asp:button i will write `<asp:button SkinID ="btnSkinBlue" runat = "server"/>`.

What to write for a user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We require register tag
<%@ Register Src="../../UserControls/RoundedButton.ascx" TagName="RoundedButton" TagPrefix="ttl" %>

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used skins with web custom controls, but I expect it to work like:

Ont the aspx:

```
<yourTag:CustomButton SkinID ="btnSkinBlue" runat = "server"/>
```

On the skin file:

```
<yourTag:CustomButton SkinID ="btnSkinBlue" runat = "server" CssClass="someclass" />
```

In the skin file, for defaults:

```
<yourTag:CustomButton runat = "server" CssClass="defaultClass" />
```

Comment: with the above stuff you also requires Register tag "<%@ Register Src="../../UserControls/RoundedButton.ascx" TagName="RoundedButton" TagPrefix="ttl" %>"

Comment: @Miral yes, as you do in any aspx page :)